# How to set size of backButton in navigation controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

In my navigation controller I have this button:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "backArrow")
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "backArrow")
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

How can I edit the size of the backButton?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the UIImage before you assign it to the back button.

Answer (score 0):

The Back Button of the navigation controller is customisable. But you can change only the text on it.

So try using the BarButtonItem instead. And one more point is that your BarButtonItem must be bigger in size compared to the one which navigation controller provides by default.